# Is there any way to create a boolean input to a ShaderNodeGroup in Blender 4.x using python?

Tags: python, node-editor, geometry-nodes, interface, compositing-nodes

I'm working now on a plugin that includes NodeGroups and I want to make a Boolean Socket. I remember that in the older versions it was possible to do this, but in the Interface system, I didn't really find a way because it limits to very specific types of input when creating a Socket.
So is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

In Blender 4.1 you can do

```
bpy.data.node_groups['NodeGroup'].interface.new_socket(
    name='My Socket',
    in_out='INPUT',
    socket_type='NodeSocketBool',
)
```

The easiest way to find out what enums you can pass for `socket_type` is to pass a wrong one and read the error message. Here you would get

```
TypeError: NodeTreeInterface.new_socket(): error with keyword argument "socket_type"
-  enum "X" not found in (
    'NodeSocketBool',
    'NodeSocketVector',
    'NodeSocketInt',
    'NodeSocketShader',
    'NodeSocketFloat',
    'NodeSocketColor'
)
```

Comment: Strange, What I get in the error show me just those ones:

TypeError: NodeTreeInterface.new_socket(): error with keyword argument "socket_type" -  enum "NodeSocketBool" not found in **('NodeSocketVector', 'NodeSocketShader', 'NodeSocketFloat', 'NodeSocketColor')**

Comment: Oh, I see that it works in 4.1, but not 4.0.

Comment: Alright, I'll upgrade soon